# How do I send emails programatically via .NET with an Exchange server that doesn't have a public SMTP? (NOT SMTP)

Tags: .net, asp.net, email, exchange-server

Question about says it all, the server I'm working with doesn't have and smtp port for me to access but you can connect to it via an iphones "Connect to exchange server" in the mail app, and people can send and receive emails so surely you should be able to do it via .net somehow.  Only ports available on the server are the defaults for http and https.  So I'm guessing there is some protocol it is using other than smtp?

If you could at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: Proprietary exchange protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119.aspx).

There is a nice `.net` interface, the [Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710.aspx).  You will need an administrator to enable EWS, as per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597941.aspx).

To discover the service endpoint, you can either [use auto-discovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597939.aspx), if the administrator wants to enable it, or you can [explicitly set a UR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633692.aspx)L to access, which will look like `https://machine.domain.contoso.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx`.

Comment: This is correct - MAPI is another option but it's antiquated and not the official recommendation from Microsoft anymore

Comment: Are those turned on by default on the Exchange server or will I have to request they be turned on by the server admin? Is there a default location of the services? ie: mail.yourscompany.com/ws?

Comment: @chuck, updated to answer.  Microsoft has some pretty good docs on the subject.

Comment: Hey thanks, I'm hoping the server admin will allow this to be enabled, and I'm hoping I'll be able to communicate with the webservices once that happens.  I'm using monotouch for the IPHone so I have a limited .net library, but I have been able to do everything else with webservices. thanks again